# Copying reflected generic type value

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Alright, so I have a generic copy method.

In my class I have a class called GenericPrimitiveContainer - which just holds T Value.

In my generic copy method, I want to copy Value from instance A to instance B.

So far it looks like this:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(props[i].PropertyType);
var container = props[i].GetValue(source, null);
```

These give me the new instance (instance) and the one I'm copying from (container).

I can say something like this:

```
(instance as GenericPrimitiveContainer<int>).Value = (container as GenericPrimitiveContainer<int>).Value;
```

But that's not very generic. If I remove the 'int', then it tells me 'type expected', and if I remove the angular brackets it won't work either.

I know the type I want, and that type is in a Type[] called genericArgs. But if I put  in there, it also won't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is the following approach:

```
private T Copy<T>(T original)
{
    Type type = original.GetType();
    var copy = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    var props = type.GetProperties();           
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        // Get the value of the original objects property
        var originalPropertyValue = prop.GetValue(original, null);

        // Set the value to the new objects property
        prop.SetValue(copy, originalPropertyValue);
    }
    return copy;
}
```